# How get page number into material-react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I`m using library [Material-React-Table](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/pagination). And I want see, what current page and what current rows number is choiece.
How can I got page number and rows count if I use class components React?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Row} from "react-bootstrap";
import {MaterialReactTable} from "material-react-table";


class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     isLoading: true,
     pagination: {pageSize: '', pageIndex: ''},
    }
  }
  
  handlePaginationChange (event) {
      console.log(event)
  }

  render() {
      <Row style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
        <MaterialReactTable
          columns={Columnt}
          data={data}
          state={{isLoading: this.state.isLoading}}
          onPaginationChange={this.handlePaginationChange}
          />
      </Row>
  }
}
```